# Colletions.sort() method is not working as expected

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to run a simple `ArrayList` program.I have used `collections.sort()` method in it but I am not getting output sorted.
Is there any problem in the way i am using `collections.sort()` method?

Please help me in finding the root cause.

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class Vector1 {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>();

            arraylist.add("Register.classname");
            arraylist.add("com.jdbc.driver");
            arraylist.add("create Statement");
            arraylist.add("String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);");
            arraylist.add("execute Statement");

            Vector<String> vectorlist=new Vector<String>();
            vectorlist.add("Register.classname");
            vectorlist.add("com.jdbc.driver");
            vectorlist.add("create Statement");
            vectorlist.add("String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);");
            vectorlist.add("execute Statement");

            Collections.sort(arraylist);
            Collections.sort(vectorlist);

            for(int i=0; i<arraylist.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Arraylist:"+arraylist.get(i));
            }
            for(int j=0;j<arraylist.size();j++)
            {
            System.out.println("Vectorlist:"+vectorlist.get(j));    

            }




        }
    }


    Output:
    Arraylist:Register.classname
    Arraylist:String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);
    Arraylist:com.jdbc.driver
    Arraylist:create Statement
    Arraylist:execute Statement
    Vectorlist:Register.classname
    Vectorlist:String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);
    Vectorlist:com.jdbc.driver
    Vectorlist:create Statement
    Vectorlist:execute Statement
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see in your sorted output?

Comment: the upper-bound of your second for-loop should be `j < vectorList.size()`.

Comment: @mre both vectorList.size() and arrayList.size()are same size

Comment: @ling.s, I know, and OP is lucky that they are.

Comment: Stop downvoting and have a look at skeety answer :)

Comment: Why people are downvoting this question.This site means is if we are not clear with a perticular concept  we should post it in the community to get feedback that's what i did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That *is* sorted. It's just sorted according to [`String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) which is an ordinal lexicographic comparison. In Unicode, all the ASCII capital letters come earlier than the ASCII lower case letters, which is why you're getting the result you're getting.

If you want a case-insensitive comparison, you should pass a `Comparator<String>` to `Collections.sort` - for example, a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

As an aside, this code is broken:

```
for(int j=0;j<arraylist.size();j++)
{
    System.out.println("Vectorlist:"+vectorlist.get(j));    
}
```

You should be using `vectorlist.size()`. Or, better, use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (String item : vectorlist) {
    System.out.println("Vectorlist: " + item);
}
```

Comment: +1, amazes me that even on simple questions I can still learn something, thanks Jon!

Comment: Thank you Jon and all of you.i forgetted the ASCII capital letter comes earlier than the ASCII lower letters.

Answer (score 2):

This is your output:

```
Register.classname
String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);
com.jdbc.driver
create Statement
execute Statement
```

And that seems to be correct order **Alphabetically**. What else did you expect?

`Collections#Sort` uses default implementation of `compareTo` of `java.lang.String` and that is to order the String Alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

The output is ordered Alphabetically:

```
Arraylist:Register.classname
Arraylist:String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);
Arraylist:com.jdbc.driver
Arraylist:create Statement
Arraylist:execute Statement
```

Keep in mind that A-Z come before a-z.

In order to sort case insensitive use:

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {              
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The sorting is correct. Default string sorting is applied to collection. Sorting is done based on ASCII value of start letter in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

To ignore case while using Collection.sort(), you should write your own Comparator

```
public class IgnoreCase implements Comparator<Object> {
        public int compare(Object i, Object j) {
            String a = (String) i;
            String b = (String) j;
            return a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

Collections.sort(arraylist, new IgnoreCase ());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correctly sorted alphabetically.

As you can see in the ascii table `http://www.asciitable.com/` uppercase Characters come before lowercase Chracters.

So:

- `XXXXXXXX:String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);`

come before:

- `XXXXXXXX:com.jdbc.driver` if they have the same prefix.

If you want to sort strings regardless of their case, use a case insentive comparator:

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
Collections.sort(vectorlist, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Then your output will be:

Output:

```
Arraylist:com.jdbc.driver
Arraylist:create Statement
Arraylist:execute Statement
Arraylist:Register.classname
Arraylist:String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);
Vectorlist:com.jdbc.driver
Vectorlist:create Statement
Vectorlist:execute Statement
Vectorlist:Register.classname
Vectorlist:String Sql=Create table hello(column1 Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting your strings, and the sort is working correctly. However, you didn't realize the structure of the Unicode character set. Characters 0-127 of Unicode are the same as the ASCII set, and capital letters precede minuscule letters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters for a list.  So, *Register* precedes *create*, and so on.

If you want case-insensitive sorting, or culture-sensitive matching, you should use the `Collator` and `CollationKey` classes.